# Color specific datatable cells based on their factor values

Tags: r, dt

I have the dataframe below:

```
product<-c("ab","ab","ab","ac","ac","ac")
shop<-c("sad","sad","sad","sadas","fghj","xzzv")
category<-c("a","a","a","b","b","b")
tempr<-c(35,35,14,24,14,5)
value<-c(0,0,-6,8,4,0)
store<-data.frame(product,shop,category,tempr,value)
```

from which I create `store2` with:

```
store2 <- matrix(NA,ncol=length(unique(store$shop)),nrow=length(unique(store$product)))
colnames(store2) <- unique(store$shop)
rownames(store2) <- unique(store$product)

for(i in 1:ncol(store)) {
  store2[store[i,'product'],store[i,'shop']] <- paste0(store[i,c('tempr')],'(',store[i,'value'],')')
}
```

I would like to create a datatable with the `DT` package colored according to the values of this new dataframe. More specifically if the number inside the parenthesis is positive then the cell should be colored green. In any other case (negative, 0 or NA its should be colored red. This is an example : 
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't necessarily recommend this approach because I am fairly against embedding one language in another, but I think it solves your ask. You can probably save the JavaScript to a file and load that into a variable, and that would be a better approach I think, but, in the interest of a self-contained solution, I have inlined it.

Based on the `DT` documentation here, https://rstudio.github.io/DT/functions.html, it is clear that the desired approach is to use `formatStyle` in some way.

`DT` provides a few convenience methods to be used with `formatStyle`, whose source is here: https://github.com/rstudio/DT/blob/0b9710f5a9391c634a3865961083740f1cbf657b/R/format.R, which I have based my solution on.

Basically, we need to pass some JavaScript to `formatStyle` which will do all of the table styling based on a variable called `value`. We will need to do something like this:

```
datatable(store2) %>% formatStyle(colnames(store2), backgroundColor=JS(jsFunc))
```

Where the variable `jsFunc` is some JavaScript string. Since the source indicates this string must be an expression rather than a statement, and because this will be somewhat complicated, we will use an anonymous function which is immediately evaluated to perform the logic. This function must take a value and return a color based on that value. Here is the function we need.

```
function(value){
  // find a number preceeded by an open parenthesis with an optional minus sign
  var matches = /\((-?\d+)/.exec(value);
  // ignore values which do not match our pattern, returning white as the background color
  if(!matches || matches.length < 2) { 
    return 'white'; 
  }
  // attempt to convert the match we found into a number
  var int = parseInt(matches[1]); 
  // if we can't ignore it and return a white color
  if(isNaN(int)) { 
    return 'white';
  } 
  // if the value is negative, return red
  if(int < 0) { 
    return 'red' 
  }
  // otherwise, by default, return green
  return 'green';
}
```

We want to call this function immediately, so we wrap it in parenthesis, and pass the value argument to it.

```
(function(value){
  // find a number preceeded by an open parenthesis with an optional minus sign
  var matches = /\((-?\d+)/.exec(value);
  // ignore values which do not match our pattern, returning white as the background color
  if(!matches || matches.length < 2) { 
    return 'white'; 
  }
  // attempt to convert the match we found into a number
  var int = parseInt(matches[1]); 
  // if we can't ignore it and return a white color
  if(isNaN(int)) { 
    return 'white';
  } 
  // if the value is negative, return red
  if(int < 0) { 
    return 'red';
  }
  // otherwise, by default, return green
  return 'green';
})(value)
```

We wrap this value in a multi-line `R` string, escape any backslashes and double-quotes (I avoided using them), and assign it to the value `jsFunc`.

```
jsFunc <- "(function(value){
  // find a number preceeded by an open parenthesis with an optional minus sign
  var matches = /\\((-?\\d+)/.exec(value);
  // ignore values which do not match our pattern, returning white as the background color
  if(!matches || matches.length < 2) { 
    return 'white'; 
  }
  // attempt to convert the match we found into a number
  var int = parseInt(matches[1]); 
  // if we can't ignore it and return a white color
  if(isNaN(int)) { 
    return 'white';
  } 
  // if the value is negative, return red
  if(int < 0) { 
    return 'red' 
  }
  // otherwise, by default, return green
  return 'green';
})(value)"
```

Finally, we can call `formatStyle` using this variable

```
datatable(store2) %>% formatStyle(colnames(store2), backgroundColor=JS(jsFunc))
```

That should give us a result like:

[image: Colored DataTable]

Comment: I like your approach a lot. I will accept this.The combination of 2 languages may be very useful indeed.

Comment: Is it possible to exclude the rownames (ab,ac) of our dataframe from this function? There may be symbols sometimes there that match the criteria and they are colored as well, but they shouldnt.

Answer (score 2):

I have an answer using `data.table` and `DT`, its a bit tricky. Here it is:

```
library(data.table)
library(DT)

store <- setDT(store)
store[,plouf := paste0(tempr,"(",value,")")]
store[,color := ifelse(value > 0,1,0)]

table1 <- dcast(store[,.SD[1],.SDcols = c("product","shop"),by = plouf],product ~ shop,value.var = "plouf")
table2 <- dcast(store[,.SD[1],.SDcols = c("product","shop","color"),by = plouf],product ~ shop,value.var = "color")
table2[,names(table2)[-1] :=  lapply(.SD,function(x){ifelse(is.na(x),0,x)}),.SDcols = names(table2)[-1] ]
setnames(table2,paste0(names(table1),"_col"))

plouf <- cbind(table1,table2[,-1])

datatable(plouf) %>% 
  formatStyle(names(table1)[-1],paste0(names(table1)[-1],"_col"), backgroundColor = styleEqual(c(0, 1), c('red', 'green')))
```

The explanation: first, i redo your `store2` table using `dacst` (passing to large format), which is more convenient, and that i ll reuse to define the colors:

```
store <- setDT(store)
store[,plouf := paste0(tempr,"(",value,")")]
table1 <- dcast(store[,.SD[1],.SDcols = c("product","shop"),by = plouf],product ~ shop,value.var = "plouf")

   product  fghj    sad sadas xzzv
1:      ab    NA  35(0)    NA   NA
2:      ac 14(4) 14(-6) 24(8) 5(0)
```

Here `store[,.SD[1],.SDcols = c("product","shop"),by = plouf]` allow to have only one line per data you want, to avoid replica

Then I do the same, but with a variable that gives the color (1 for green, 0 for red):

```
store[,color := ifelse(value > 0,1,0)]
table2 <- dcast(store[,.SD[1],.SDcols = c("product","shop","color"),by = plouf],product ~ shop,value.var = "color")

   product fghj sad sadas xzzv
1:      ab   NA   0    NA   NA
2:      ac    1   0     1    0
```

I tranform Nas into 0 in all column exept the first one:

```
table2[,names(table2)[-1] :=  lapply(.SD,function(x){ifelse(is.na(x),0,x)}),.SDcols = names(table2)[-1] ]

   product fghj sad sadas xzzv
1:      ab    0   0     0    0
2:      ac    1   0     1    0
```

and modify the names of the second table (giving the colors):

```
setnames(table2,paste0(names(table1),"_col"))
```

you then bind the two

```
plouf <- cbind(table1,table2[,-1])
```

and use `DT` where you specify different column : one for the target, one for the background color

```
datatable(plouf) %>% 
  formatStyle(names(table1)[-1],paste0(names(table1)[-1],"_col"), backgroundColor = styleEqual(c(0, 1), c('red', 'green')))
```

[image]

I had to change your data, because there wasn't an unique set for each shop. Here are the data:

```
product<-c("ab","ab","ac","ac","ac","ac")
shop<-c("sad","sad","sad","sadas","fghj","xzzv")
category<-c("a","a","a","b","b","b")
tempr<-c(35,35,14,24,14,5)
value<-c(0,0,-6,8,4,0)
store<-data.frame(product,shop,category,tempr,value)
```